# Invalid object name dbo tablename - Entity Framework works on IIS but not on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, azure-web-app-service

I'm encountering an issue with Entity Framework when trying to retrieve data from a table using the following code:

```
var firstPerson _deskAssignmentContextBackup.People.First();
```

The error message I'm receiving is: "Invalid object name 'dbo.People'".

The peculiar thing is that this error only occurs when the application is deployed to Azure as an App Service. When I deploy the exact same code to my local IIS, everything works perfectly fine. This leads me to believe that the problem is not with the database or the DbContext configurations.

The context used for this operation was created using the database-first approach, ensuring that both the connection and the database structure match perfectly between environments.

I suspect there might be an underlying configuration difference or environment-specific factor that is causing this behavior.

Below is the code snippet for the DbContext:

```
public class DeskAssignmentContextBackup : DbContext
{
    public DeskAssignmentContextBackup()
    {
    }

    public DeskAssignmentContextBackup(DbContextOptions<DeskAssignmentContextBackup> options)
      : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual DbSet<Supervisor> Supervisors { get; set; } = null!;


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
      {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_dbo.People");
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id, "IX_Id");
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.SupervisorId, "IX_Supervisor_Id");

        entity.Property(e => e.EndDate).HasColumnType("datetime");
        entity.Property(e => e.SupervisorId).HasColumnName("Supervisor_Id");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Supervisor).WithMany(p => p.People)
          .HasForeignKey(d => d.SupervisorId)
          .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.People_dbo.Supervisors_Supervisor_Id");
      });

      modelBuilder.Entity<Supervisor>(entity =>
      {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_dbo.Supervisors");
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id, "IX_Id");
      });
    }
  }
```

Any insights or guidance on how to further troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Check the database if table exists there

Comment: Yes, it exists. Like I said, it works perfect for the same code deployed to IIS.

Comment: And your connection string is not different from local env?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same, I didn't change anything. Also, connecting to another database on the same SQL server works.

Comment: Where's the Azure App pulling the connection string from? Application Settings in Azure or the web.config/appsettings?

Comment: Entity has two modes Create and Update.  The database may already exist.  The error message is coming from the SQL Server.  You can check log files by using SQL Server Management Studio and the log files are in the explorer under Management.  Check the login in the logs for user and group.  See if they are the same as the working database.  It probably is a permission issue that the database dbo.People is not getting created or not getting updated.  Also check if the database exists on the server.  The issue could be the connection string.

Comment: If there is setting for connection string in azure it will take it first, if not it will take it from appsettings

Comment: connection strings are in the appsettings.json. What is interesting, I'm making connections to 2 databases on the same server. And to both of them I have connection string in the same file. Both looks the same, just initial catalog is different. And connecting to one works, to the second don't. But only in Azure. When the app is deployed to IIS, it works.

Comment: I have not connection strings in Azure

Comment: I've checked login logs, there is no error login for this database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the issue and the solution.

The problem was that Azure was automatically generating an appsettings.production.json file, which I didn't notice because it wasn't present in my project; I only had appsettings.json.

When I was verifying connection strings, I was checking appsettings.json. However, it turned out that in the appsettings.production.json file, Azure wasn't copying the connection strings from appsettings.json, but rather from the publish profile. This is where the problem arose.

When my contexts were being located, an error occurred at some point, and all databases were assigned the same connection string. This was the reason why one database was working while the other was not.

I'm referring to this particular moment:

[image: publish profile - databases]

I want to express my gratitude to everyone for their suggestions; now I have a better understanding of how this works.

Answer (score 2):

This error is apparently due to the inability to find the `dbo.People` table.

If I understood you correctly, you are running your db queries on two different environments. The first one is local and the second one is Azure.

So, if the table `dbo.People` really exists (please double-check), I would recommend that you check if the user has the appropriate **rights to run the query**.

Also, please check schema and name, maybe, there is `dbo.People`**s**, or **public**`.People`.

Comment: The first deployment is on IIS, hosted on the same server where the database exists (I've verified this multiple times). In the connection string, I have declared the 'User Id' and 'Password'. Interestingly, this configuration works flawlessly when deployed on IIS, indicating that the issue is unlikely related to user rights or the database schema. If it were a user rights or schema issue, it would not work on IIS either

Comment: Additionally, it doesn't work when attempting to retrieve data from the 'Supervisors' table. Furthermore, I have a duplicate of this database on another server. Surprisingly, even after updating the connection string to connect to the duplicate database, the issue still persists on Azure, whereas it functions correctly on IIS.

Comment: Well, check if the deployed code on Azure is the same as the code you have deployed on IIS. Rebuild the project. Try to debug it using attached debugger.